# Trying to show input under dynamic generated content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have the input from #modifyForm (which is not display by default) to be shown under the card where the link modify was clicked. For now, it only toggle under the first card or under all the cards at the same time. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
<div class="row rowcards">
           {% for community in data %}
          <div class="col-md-3" id="removable">
            <div class="card"> 
              <div class="card-body">
                <a href="#" id="threedot" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></a>
                <!-- menu -->
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <p class="text-center"><a href="#" class="modifylink">{{ 'Modifiy' | trans }}</a></p>
                  <p class="text-center"><a href="#" data-id="{{community.id}}" class="text-danger deletelink"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>{{ 'Delete' | trans }}</a></p>
                </div>
                <p class="card-title">{{ community.info.name }}</p>
                <p class="card-text"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> 4 membres</p>
                <div class="text-center"> 
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-card"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> {{ 'Add member' | trans }}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form data-id="{{community.id}}" id="modifyForm">
          <div class="form-group modifyform">
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Changez le nom de votre communauté</small>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

The jquery :

```
$(document).on('click', '.modifylink', function() { 
$('#removable #modifyForm').toggle(500)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- This Is because `Id` should be unique so don't use same id for more than one element .. change all of `id`s in any loop to `class`s
- Then you can use `$(this).closest('.removable').find('.modifyForm').toggle(500)`

Comment: NVM .. You're totally welcome @Amaury .. Have a great day :-)